# How do I request a specific broadcast intent for data entering on a socket?

Tags: android, sockets, android-intent, tcp, broadcastreceiver

So I have an application that scans the available wifi networks, and if it finds the specific one it's looking for (which is saved in shared preferences) it will automatically connect to it and open a TCP client socket (Socket class) to exchange messages with the server. The device that is broadcasting the Wifi SSID is acting as the server.

At the moment the code listening for incoming messages on the client runs a  continuous while loop checking if there is data in the BufferedReader, which seems inefficient but is done in all the examples I've seen.

Is there a way to configure a broadcast intent or message (or some other API), which when the Android OS recognises there is data coming in on that socket, (and is terminated by a carriage return line feed) will send out an intent or message which I can listen for and then decide to act on, rather than just constantly polling the BufferedReader and wasting CPU time?

Thanks.

Comment: `it and open a TCP socket for comms.`. A server socket? What is comms? Communications?  `the code listening for incoming messages on the socket `. If it is a server socket then you should have code to accept new clients on that socket. Please edit your post to make things clear.

Comment: Just edited my question, thanks for the suggested edits, it should be more clear now.